# Add variable to Magento session from javascript

Tags: javascript, session, magento

I have a Tax-toggle button on every page of a Magento store, and want to remember the settings that the user chooses.

The toggle works using javascript, and successfully changes all prices on the page.

However, I would like to remember what they have chosen and the Magento session seems like the ideal way to do this. Is this something I can achieve from javascript? Would the only way be to have it call an external php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that setting new cookies was the way to go as per @JRM, but I didn't want to use JQuery since this is not loaded by default by Magento. I therefore used the following:

Setting the cookie:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(60*24*60*60*1000));
document.cookie = 'showVAT=true; expires='+date.toGMTString()+'; path=/';
```

Then to load on pageload:

```
name = 'showVAT=';
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var parts = document.cookie.split(/;\s*/);
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
    {
        var part = parts[i];
        if (part.indexOf(name) == 0)
        if(part.substring(name.length)=="true") respondToClickOn()
        if(part.substring(name.length)=="false") respondToClickOff();
    }
});
```

Useful resources on [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), though I didn't use his script. And also https://stackoverflow.com/a/180271/952572 which is very similar to the first.

Answer (score 2):

I work with Magento as well and I use jQuery to edit the session cookie: http://www.akchauhan.com/manage-add-edit-delete-cookies-in-jquery/

Comment: Are you simply creating a new cookie to use? so `$.cookie("showTax", "yes");` or similar?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don;t use JQuery on Magento for anything else, so don't want to load it just for this, but you pointed me in the right direction. uv.