# Div contents not getting cookie value

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a div as follows:

```
<div class="bubbly">
 </div>
 <script>
 $('.bubbly').innerHTML=getCookie('adjective');
 </script>
```

But the content in this div cannot be seen. 
If i alert the cookie, i get the value in it. 
But the div is not taking the value of cookie.
I want to have the contents of the cookie in this div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use native DOM properties in a jquery object then do like this:

```
$('.bubbly')[0].innerHTML=getCookie('adjective');
```

You can do the same all in jquery like this:

```
$('.bubbly').html(getCookie('adjective'));
```

Also make sure to enclose your DOM manipulating code in a handler for the 
DOM ready event, like this:

```
<div class="bubbly">
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.bubbly').html(getCookie('adjective'));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing what looks like jQuery with plain JavaScript. So either you have to use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to set the content of the element:

```
$('.bubbly').html(getCookie('adjective'));
```

Or you have to get the DOM element out of the jQuery object if you want to use the native innerHTML property:

```
$('.bubbly')[0].innerHTML = getCookie('adjective');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more problem... how do we check if a cookie is set using javascript or jQuery?

Comment: @ChetanaKestikar This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135801/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-cookie-by-name-in-javascript) suggest a couple of ways to do it. There are also jQuery plugins like [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) that you could use if your prefer that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.bubbly').html(getCookie('adjective'));
```

assuming that your getCookie function works properly. `innerHTML` is a pure JavaScript thing.