# Javascript - checking if cookie exists on page load isn't working for me

Tags: javascript, cookies, if-statement

I have the follwing code :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  function myfuncc () {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {
    // They've been here before.
    alert("hello again");
  }
  else {
    // set a new cookie
    expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setTime(date.getTime()+(10*60*1000)); // Ten minutes

    // Date()'s toGMTSting() method will format the date correctly for a cookie
    document.cookie = "visited=yes; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
    alert("this is your first time");
  }
  }


  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = myfuncc;
  </script>
```

As you can see the window.onload function, I am trying to check if a vistor had already been at the site once the page loads. I am using cookies to do so. Problem is, I can't see the messages I am supposed to. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Looks fine. Do you overwrite `window.onload` afterwards, in further scripts?

Comment: which browser? IE doesn't support indexOf.

Comment: "IE doesn't support indexOf" Don't be silly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: I got nuts on that, believe me: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the expire date using `toUTCString()` method. 
You also have a `date` object that is not initialized, try this:

```
function myfuncc () {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {
        // They've been here before.
        alert("hello again");
    }
    else {

        var expiry = new Date();
        expiry.setTime(expiry.getTime()+(10*60*1000)); // Ten minutes

        document.cookie = "visited=yes; expires=" + expiry.toUTCString();

        alert("this is your first time");
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work... I can't even see the messages "hello..."

Comment: Ok, your answer helped but I had another problem... I fixed it by adding the onload function in another place. thanks.

Comment: Nice, check it as an anwser to help other users :)

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
var testarr = ["knirpsel", "text", "visited=yes"].indexOf("visited");
alert ( testarr );
```

output is `"-1"` which means the string `"visited=yes"` won't be found by search term `"visited"`

http://jsfiddle.net/m5x3M/

and

[What is the best way to get a cookie by name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135801/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-cookie-by-name-in-javascript)